# vs2010 debug vs release: why the stl list is interpret wrong

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stl

I have a program passing a stl list to an dll, when both modules are in debugging mode, everything works fine. When change the dll to release mode, the passing does not work any more. I checked the list in the main app (debugging version) and examined the list size to be 16 bytes, immediately in the dll I examined the list size now changes to 12 bytes. and everything in the list are wrongly interpret. I checked the compiler option and has doubt on the structure alignment, but did not get any clue. Anybody can give me some hints? Thanks a lot.

passing structure:

```
class data
{
int
int
char*
double
}

class datalist
{
int 
int 
int 
list<data> list1
list<data> list2
};
```

passing mechanism:

```
fun(const datalist& dl)
```

*More clarifications:

```
main app (debug) + dll (debug): work fine
main app (release) + dll (release): does not work
main app (debug) +dll (release): does not work
```

both modules are compiled with the same compiler vs2010*

Comment: Some code please !  The question is very broad and abstract otherwise !

Comment: You can't mix and match code that has iterator debugging en/disabled.

Comment: Thanks Hans. Actually this is the right answer. Can someone promote this as the answer. Add _Iterator_Debugger=0 to the preprocessor definition and rebuild the main application, and the problem solved. The reason is: the debug build enable the option and the stl container contains some extra data members which makes the two modules mismatch.

Comment: I do not know why people give me a finger down. Am I asking a meaningless question? Actually the /MD is also a solution, but the reason is due to the extra data member under different compiler option. In my opinion, the stl container using this kind of implementation is not good.

Answer (score 3):

Your DLL is using a different version of the C++ standard library than your application is, so each has it's own (incompatible) version of `std::list`. You have to rebuild your DLL with the same compiler and configuration you're building your application with (Visual Studio 2010, Release).

Comment: both modules are compiled using the same copy of vs2010

Comment: @shangping but are you using a debug version of the dll with the release version of the app (or vice versa)

Answer (score 0):

```
main app (debug) + dll (debug): work fine
main app (release) + dll (release): does not work
main app (debug) +dll (release): does not work
```

Native DLL's are a very raw low level mechanism. If the compiler of the App and the DLL have different settings, there's no inherent way for either side to know that the other is making different choices. So you as the developer have to ensure that everything is compatible.

In the case of debug vs release, the differences are often too significant. So just don't ever mix things like that.

For the case of your release builds not working together, you should check over all the compiler/linker settings on each project and ensure that they are compatible (which generally means having them exactly the same).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. We actually uses same settings. Some progress: if we use /MD the error is gone. I used /MT for both projects previously. What are the differences between /MT and /MD anyway? Thanks

Comment: @shangping Ah yes, I forgot about that setting. /MT means linking the C/C++ runtime directly into the exe/dll. /MD means linking against the runtime as a dll. When two separate things link it directly via /MT, they each get their own heaps (among other things). When linking to it under /MD, everything is shared. So when trying to pass a complex object which manages memory allocations (such as `list`) across an exe/dll boundry /MT will be a problem but /MD will work fine.